# Not able to displaying answer-er Video with the sdpOffer of Offer-er. using WEBRTC

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc, sdp

I am not able to displaying answer-er Video with the sdpOffer of Offer-er. using WEBRTC.
Here is my code.could you please help me out. I don't understand Where am going wrong in my code.

```
var offer;
function getPeerOffer(video_stream) {
    var message = {
        id : 'Viwer'                       
    }                      
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
    ws.onmessage=function(message){
         var obj = JSON.parse(message.data)                             
         offer = obj.sdpOffer
         answererPeer2(offer, video_stream); 
    }
}

function answererPeer2(offer, video_stream) {

    answerer = new RTCPeerConnection(null);
    answerer.addStream(video_stream);
    answerer.onaddstream =function (event) {                       
        offererToAnswerer.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.stream);
        offererToAnswerer.play();
    };
    answerer.onicecandidate = function (event) {
        if (!event || !event.candidate) return;
        answerer.addIceCandidate(event.candidate);
    };

    var remoteDescription = new RTCSessionDescription(offer);
    answerer.setRemoteDescription(remoteDescription);                  
    answerer.createAnswer(function (answer) {
    answerer.setLocalDescription(answer);
    answerer.addStream(video_stream)
    }, function() {}, video_constraints);
}          

var video_constraints = {
    mandatory: {},
    optional: []
};
function getUserMedia(callback) {
    var n = navigator;
    n.getMedia = n.webkitGetUserMedia || n.mozGetUserMedia;
    n.getMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true
    }, callback, onerror);
    function onerror(e) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(e, null, '\t'));
    }
}           
getUserMedia(function (video_stream) {                
        getPeerOffer(video_stream)       
    });

}
```

Comment: I do not see you sending the answer... i.e the remote peer receiving you sdp

Comment: In my case Answer-er will only view the video like just a receiver.

Comment: i get that, but still you need to set the sdp to complete the call

Comment: @mido22 c m quite new in WEBRTC Will you please explain me little detail what you want to say and if i got some good tutorial then that will be really helpful. Actually i m bit confuse where i have to add the sdp offer to complete the call.

Comment: [this](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/webrtc-for-newbies.html) would be a good place to start, if you are looking for code, it is already [here](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/one-to-many-video-broadcasting)

Comment: @mido22 thanks for your articles let me implements those first then i will let you know if i am facing any farther problem